# What is the meaning of ''slam dunk'' when used in justice?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard this phrase: "this case is a slam dunk" told by someone having to do with justice system. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what does that mean.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Deppy. We expect people to do a little research before asking a question.In this case, you could look up slam dunk in a good dictionary, for example this one; https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slam%20dunk and you would find that it means a **sure thing - eg this case is a slam dunk** .If you are unsure what this might mean in a legal situation,  please edit your answer to explain what you don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

See this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_dunk) article, especially:

> The phrase "slam dunk" has since entered popular usage in American English, meaning a "sure thing": an action with a guaranteed outcome, or a similarly impressive achievement, in the same way that the baseball-inspired phrases "step up to the plate" or "he hit it out of the park" were more commonly used in previous years.

It means guaranteed, or an open-and-shut case, implying that the actual trial is just a formality - so overwhelming is the evidence.